# New Laptop Charger starts and stops charging

Tags: charger

I have a Lenovo Y50-70 laptop, and A lost its charger a while ago. Its chargers output was 20v 6.75A, so I bought a 20v 6.75A Lenovo charger from somewhere (but it doesn't look like my old one and its possible that its not the official charger but i guess its 20v 6.75A so i suppose it should work for me anyway).

Not the problem is that sometimes the charger works well but sometimes it goes crazy and then when I plug it in it works for a while like 10 secs to few minutes and then it stops charging without me changing anything at all.

I don't know if its important but its a rather noisy charger not that it makes a lot of noise but if you listen carefully you can easily hear its noise. but when its not charging the laptop then there is no noise even if it's connected both to the laptop and power source.

When it stops charging, if i immediately disconnect and connect it nothing will happen, also I believe if i disconnect it only from laptop, nothing will happen but if i disconnect it from the power and wait for a while and connect it again then it will work for a short while and then stop again.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: If its not a lenovo charger, it's probably a cheap one from china. It is probably a cheap design or broken. Get a new one.

Comment: You should trust laptop in this one

Comment: I once used chinese charger. So one night i worked and then it exploded, with bang and sparks, and blew up the fuses. Fortunately hard disk survived, but nothing else, not even a keyboard.

Comment: I had a Chinese battery charger for a gopro, the first time I plugged it in it started smoking. Its not worth the risk of burning your house down to save 10$.

Comment: No its not that crappy, it has 6 months change warranty    and stuff I'm electrically wondering why is this happening.